# Websockets not working on my network

Tags: websocket

Websockets applications are not working on my network.
However, websites like http://www.websocket.org/echo.html and http://websocketstest.com/ tell me that everything is working.

When trying an application of my own, it appears the handshake goes through successfully, but after that none of the messages get across.

Any ideas what could be the reason for this? An explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with "on my network" ? Do you have a server on your network?

Comment: The "network" is in a school, but there's no server. The internet line  goes directly into the router, and I don't see any settings that would block ws (though I could be missing something)

Comment: A school? It could be under a parental control filter/proxy. Try with `wss://` instead of `ws://`

Comment: Can you try a test at http://www.netscan.co and share the results with us?

Comment: @thanpolas I'm not at the location right now, will get there and try this out. 
[at]vtortola I can't really use :wss//, but I'll try to investigate if thats the problem. But I'm surprised that the handshake goes through...

Comment: @vtortola's solution worked for me. Thanks.